# If I use ENUM type on the database field with Laravel, then incorrect result is returned

Tags: php, laravel, pdo

The 'users' field is an ENUM type.

```
$data1 = DB::select('select count(*) from users where status = 1'); //Works

$data2 = DB::select('select count(*) from users where status = ?', [1]); //returns 0 instead of 6
```

The first query returns 6 as the count, while the second one returns 0 (see image below):

[image]

but if I use PHP code without Laravel, I receive the expected output. The code is as follows:

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM `up_users` WHERE `status` = :type";
$res=$pdo->prepare($sql);
$type = 1;
$res->bindParam( ':type', $type, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$res->execute();
$row = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($row); //Works
```

Comment: This is why I hate enums, especially for integers. I've found that `1` is not the same as `'1'`, and sometimes it needs to be quoted, and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: I agree ! but my boss stick use the ENUM type , what can I do？